# OpenGL Programming Guide 7th Edition Source Code Examples

Tags: opengl

Where can I download the source code examples of the the book "OpenGL Programming Guide 7th Edition"? I have been searching web but I couldn't find anything. Book says that the source code can be downloaded from opengl-redbook.com but site doesn't exist. I know that I can copy from book but it really takes time to copy and format the code.

Comment: Try [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/wrc/courses/cg1/doc/opengl/redbook/).

Comment: @Banthar: Thanks, but there are only opengl 1.0 examples.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same quite a while now. The book refers to http://www.opengl-redbook.com/ for samples but the site seems to be down. This link has some samples but I'm not sure if they are related to the book (at least I couldn't fine icosahedron sample in there): http://www.opengl-redbook.com/source/